# Как сделать, чтобы программа сама вводила логин и пароль к расшаренной папке?

Tags: python, windows

Мне надо скопировать файлы в расшаренную папку, но перед открытием папки надо ввести логин и пароль. Можно-ли сделать так, чтобы программа сама вводила логин и пароль?

Comment: ОС Windows? Папка обычная сетевая?

Comment: @Kromster, да обычная сетевая папка в Windows

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, по каким причинам не подходит встроенный функционал ОС Windows под названием "Диспетчер учетных данных"/"Credential Manager" ?